# How to determine the volume of water necessary to produce a solution with 4.9 g/l sulfuric acid?

Tags: concentration, mole, density

> The molar mass of sulfuric acid is $M(\ce{H2SO4}) = \pu{98.1 g/mol}$.
>   We have $\pu{100 mL}$ of a $0.1$ molar solution of sulfuric acid. What volume $V$ in  $\mathrm{mL}$ of water, $\ce{H2O}$, do we have to add in order to obtain a solution that has $\pu{4.9 g/L}$ sulfuric acid?

I've done the following:

\begin{align}
M(\ce{H2SO4}) &= \pu{98.1 g/mol}\\
M(\ce{H2O})   &= \pu{18.0 g/mol}\\
\text{mass concentration of }  H_2SO_4 &= \pu{98.1 g/L}\\
c(\ce{H2SO4}) &= \pu{1 mol/L}\\
c_{\mathrm{contr}} \times V_{\mathrm{contr}} &=
c_{\mathrm{dil}}\times V_{\mathrm{dil}}\\
\Longrightarrow V_{\mathrm{dil}} &=
\frac{c_{\mathrm{conctr}}\times V_{\mathrm{conctr}}}{c_{\mathrm{dil}}}
\end{align}

The molarity of the diluted water I can't calculate with elementary formulas. So it leaves me with 2 unknowns.

I've tried using so many formulas to no avail.

What formula am I not thinking of? Or what variable am I missing?

Comment: 1) The body says "0.1 molar solution", while later you write c(H2SO4) = 1 mol/L; shouldn't the latter be 0.1 mol/L? 2) Where did you get the value for the density (rho) from? Did you just re-use the value of molar mass and change the the units? Don't do that :) You have to look up the density in tables, if it isn't given. You will then notice that the density changes in dependence of the concentration - so you had to note down, which H2SO4 concentration you are referring to when writing down the density. [Here is an example tabular](http://www.chembuddy.com/?left=CASC&right=density_tables)

Comment: @Marzipanherz  I'll change that. Yeah I shouldn't use the same notations as in physics. I'll change that too.

Comment: I see. Are you aware that this mass concentration is also referring to a 1mol/L solution, not to a 0.1molar solution the question talks about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have talked about it in chat and maybe the question is a bit ambiguous. I would interpret the last line as a [mass concentration](http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/M/M03713.html). So what you are actually looking to create is a $\gamma(\ce{H2SO4}) = \pu{4.9 g/l}$ solution. Then the calculation becomes straight forward.
Keep in mind that water is your solvent, so you can't actually dilute it; also writing down the concentration is a bit pointless here.

You can easily convert the mass concentration to an [amount concentration](http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/A/A00295.html). The relative molar mass $M$ is given by the mass $m$ of the substance divided by the amount of substance $n$:
$$M = \frac{m}{n}\tag1\label{molarmass}$$

The mass concentration is defined as 
$$\gamma = \frac{m}{V}.\tag2\label{massconc}$$
The amount concentration is defined as 
$$c = \frac{n}{V}.\tag3\label{amountconc}$$
You can use \eqref{molarmass} in \eqref{amountconc} and obtain
$$c = \frac{m}{M} \times \frac{1}{V}
=\frac{m}{V} \times \frac{1}{M}.\tag4$$
Substitute \eqref{massconc} back in and you have
$$c = \frac{\gamma}{M}.\tag5\label{amounttomass}$$

Now in the question you have given the following:
\begin{align}
M(\ce{H2SO4}) &= \pu{98.1 g/mol}\\
c_\mathrm{i}(\ce{H2SO4}) &= \pu{0.1 mol/l}\\
V_\mathrm{i}(\ce{H2SO4}) &= \pu{100 ml}\\
\gamma_\mathrm{f}(\ce{H2SO4}) &= \pu{4.9 g/l}
\end{align}
I have given the initial values the subscript $\mathrm{i}$ and the final values the subscript $\mathrm{f}$ (instead of concentrated and diluted).

You are now looking for the volume of solvent you have to add, which is 
$$\Delta V = V_\mathrm{f} - V_\mathrm{i}.\tag5\label{volume}$$

Then you are right, you need the following relation
$$c_\mathrm{i} \times V_\mathrm{i} = c_\mathrm{f} \times V_\mathrm{f},
\tag6$$
rearranged and using \eqref{amounttomass}
\begin{align}
c_\mathrm{i} \times V_\mathrm{i} &=
\frac{\gamma_\mathrm{f}}{M} \times V_\mathrm{f},\\
V_\mathrm{f} &=
\frac{M}{\gamma_\mathrm{f}} \times c_\mathrm{i} \times V_\mathrm{i},
\end{align}
and using \eqref{volume}
\begin{align}
V_\mathrm{i} + \Delta V &=
\frac{M}{\gamma_\mathrm{f}} \times c_\mathrm{i} \times V_\mathrm{i},\\
\Delta V &=
\frac{M}{\gamma_\mathrm{f}} \times c_\mathrm{i} \times V_\mathrm{i} - V_\mathrm{i}\\
&= \left(\frac{M \times c_\mathrm{i}}{\gamma_\mathrm{f}} - 1\right)V_\mathrm{i}.
\tag7\label{dilute}
\end{align}

Now simply plug in your values and get the solution (hover over box to reveal):

> $\displaystyle \Delta V = \left(\frac{\pu{98.1 g//mol} \times \pu{0.1 mol//l}}{\pu{4.9 g//l}} - 1\right)\times \pu{0.100 l} = \pu{0.100 l}.$